# in php5, how to use mysql_execute in script that has delimiter

Tags: php, mysql

Have a script that I can copy and run in *mysql* shell just fine, but explodes when attempting the same script in `php5 mysql_query`.  Part of the script:

```
-- sync shadow with users
drop trigger users_post_insert;
delimiter $$
create trigger users_post_insert after insert on users
    for each row
begin   
    insert into shadow( usr_id ) values( new.usr_id );
end$$
delimiter ;
```

Raises error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'delimiter $$\ncreate trigger users_post_insert after insert
on users\n\tfor each ro' at line 8
```

Again, have done similar executing script files with PostgresQL and Oracle scripts, so this took me off guard.

Do MySQL scripts need to be passed through a `regex` before being run, or what?

These are scripts that have been debugged and then applied via `php` to new schemas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testing shows `mysql_execute` cannot accept the DELIMITER command.

To make it work break up your file into chunks, leaving out the DELIMITER lines altogether.  For example,

```
    $procs = file_get_contents( '../sql/security.sql' ); 
    $procArr = preg_split( "/delimiter .*\n/", $procs );
```

Also, remove the set delimiter "$$" from the remaining chunks.

Feed each non-empty chunk into `mysql_execute` - it's ugly, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

Might you need to define delimiter first before executing a command, and make sure you dropped an already created trigger (or just use if exists clause) try this

```
-- sync shadow with users
delimiter $$
drop trigger if exists users_post_insert;$$
create trigger users_post_insert after insert on users
    for each row
begin   
    insert into shadow( usr_id ) values( new.usr_id );
end;$$
delimiter ;
```